# バッチファイルでHDDの有無を確認するには？

Tags: windows, batch-file

バッチファイルでHDDの接続（１つor２つ）を判断してHDDのフォーマットを自動で行いたいのですが、実現する方法がわかりません。

・HDDが１つ接続されている場合
　xGBをCドライブにして残りをDドライブにする
・HDDが2つ接続されている場合
　Disk#0をCドライブ
　Disk#1をDドライブ

「DISKPART /s <スクリプト>」を使用して上記を別々に実行することは出来ましたが、HDDの接続状況によって自動で判別してフォーマットを行いたいと考えています。

ご教授をお願いします。

Comment: HDDと曖昧に表現されていますが質問内容は「diskの有無を確認すには？」でしょうか？

Comment: はい。「diskの有無を確認するには？」になります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

基本的にはBATファイル以外の言語を使用されることをお勧めします。どうしてもBATファイルということでしたらdiskpartの `list disk` の出力内容を解析することでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

回答ありがとうございます。
バッチファイルを以下の様にすることで出来ました。

```
@echo off

echo list disk | diskpart | find "Disk 1" >NUL
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Disk 1 is Not found
) else (
    echo Find Disk 1
)
```